# Android Dagger 1.0.1: Incompatible types: Cannot convert integer[] to int[]

Tags: android, code-injection, dagger

I am using Dagger 1.0.1 in one of my projects. I was recently using 1.2.2 and everything compiled and ran fine. I wanted to introduce ProGuard into the project and was having a lot of trouble, and it sounded promising that downgrading to 1.0.1 would solve my ProGuard problems.

Now, when I try and compile my app to send to my test device, I get the following errors in my generated file outputs:

```
Error:(53, 122) error: incompatible types: Map<Integer[],FourByteMemoryMapParsedResponse> cannot be converted to Map<int[],FourByteMemoryMapParsedResponse>

Error:(53, 126) error: incompatible types: Map<Integer[],SingleByteMemoryMapParsedResponse> cannot be converted to Map<int[],SingleByteMemoryMapParsedResponse>

Error:(53, 120) error: incompatible types: Map<Integer[],TwoByteMemoryMapParsedResponse> cannot be converted to Map<int[],TwoByteMemoryMapParsedResponse>

Error:(53, 128) error: incompatible types: Map<Integer[],SingleByteMemoryMapParsedResponse> cannot be converted to Map<int[],SingleByteMemoryMapParsedResponse>

Error:(53, 122) error: incompatible types: Map<Integer[],TwoByteMemoryMapParsedResponse> cannot be converted to Map<int[],TwoByteMemoryMapParsedResponse>
```

All of these errors are within the generated files *filename*$$InjectAdapter

Any ideas on a fix?

Comment: Is there a reason you are sticking to Dagger 1? Why not use [Dagger 2](https://google.github.io/dagger/)?

Comment: Well since I was running dagger 1.2.2, and this is a fairly large project, switching to dagger 2 could mean 10's of hours of reworking/refactoring.

Switching to dagger 1.0.1 was a path I was hoping to explore before having to go down the dagger 2 path. Dagger 1.2.2 apparently uses runtime injection while 1.0.1 does not, meaning 1.0.1 can be ran with proguard easily.

Comment: `int[]` is incompatible with `Integer[]`, and `Map<int[], T>` is incompatible with `Map<Integer[], T>`. If you can show us those bindings or dependencies, that may help.